# DB2 : Length of concatenated fields different

Tags: db2

Below query gives 2 different wrong length but same numbers ,In IBM db2 SQL
Why there is 2 different length for same value ?

```
select 
  decimal(TRIM(cast(15 as char(2)))||TRIM(LPAD(cast(7 as   char(2)),2,'0'))||TRIM(LPAD(cast(13 as char(2)),2,'0'))),
  length(decimal(TRIM(cast(15 as char(2)))||TRIM(LPAD(cast(7 as char(2)),2,'0'))||TRIM(LPAD(cast(13 as char(2)),2,'0')))),
  decimal(TRIM(substr(replace(char(current_date -1 days,ISO),'-',''),3,6)),6,0),
  length(decimal(TRIM(substr(replace(char(current_date -1 days,ISO),'-',''),3,6)),6,0))
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Answer (score 0):

`DECIMAL(x,p,s)` returns a packed decimal value of precision p, scale s.

A packed decimal(p,s) only takes p/2 + 1 bytes of memory.

So 6 /2 + 1 = 4, which is the value `LENGTH()` returns for packed decimal expressions per the  (DB2 for IBM i) [manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzscalength.htm)

Answer (score 0):

These numbers are not the same value the first one is `15713` and the second is `150713`.